# React-App showing 'Error: Cannot find module 'ajv-formats''

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, ajv

I am building an e-comm-site clone with react and it was working perfectly fine until I added a 'StateProvider.js', 'reducer.js' and updated my 'index.js' to have my `<App />` wrapped like so: `<StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}> <App /> </StateProvider>`.  Now when I run 'npm start' it says:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'ajv-formats'
Require stack:

- /Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js
- /Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/index.js
- /Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js
- /Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (/Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:25:20)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  '/Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js',
  '/Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/index.js',
  '/Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js',
  '/Users/Desktop/E-Comm-Site/e-comm-site/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js'
  ]
  }.

The code is identical to that of the course I am following and it works still for them at this stage.  Although he has serviceWork.js and I have reportWebVitals.js.  Although I can't see how that would be the issue as it was working fine before?

Answer (score 1):

Run the `npm install` from the root of the project directory command in your terminal.

If the problem persists after running that and restarting your server, the dependency `ajv-formats` is referenced by your project but not listed as a dependency in your package.json file. Tou can do this by running the command `npm install ajv-formats --save`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I removed node_modules and package-lock.json and did `npm install` and the error has gone